# Delphi RLAngleLabel perca de qualidade

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, relatório

Alguém utiliza o RLAngleLabel do FortesReport? 
Esse componente perde qualidade na impressão, o que está circula é utilizando o RLAngleLabel, como podemos perceber perde qualidade. Alguém sabe se existe alguma configuração no componente para melhorar essa qualidade?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do FortesReport está utilizando?

Comment: FortesReport Community Edition 4.0 VCL

Comment: Testa ai, em Borders > Style "bsClear" :)

Comment: Não mudou nada, continua mesma coisa.

Comment: Te aconselho usar FastReport, super fácil de utilizar e a qualidade é ótima.

Comment: Já usei o FortesReport muito anos atrás e tive um problema parecido porque eu forçava o Label (ou seu componente em questão) a ficar de um tamanho específico, ou seja, eu travava o tamanho do Label (propriedade `strech` ou algo assim se não me engano). Se você estiver estiver fazendo isso, libere o label para que se redimensione automaticamente com o tamanho texto inserido e faça o teste para ver se continua distorcendo.

Comment: Ao gerar um PDF disso ele tmb fica assim ou só na visualização?

Comment: @WendelRodrigues também fica assim.

Comment: O problema esta no componente mesmo. Resolvi trocando o componente, e mudando a minha forma de imprimir a etiqueta.